# "seawave" noise on the right channel of a line array sound system

Tags: noise, speakers

I work in that community center for almost a year now. Without any warning and only when there is no input source on, you can hear a "seawave" kind of noise on the right channel of a line array sound system. It lasts only for 5 or 6 seconds.

Do you have any idea what this might be?

Comment: What do you mean by seawave? Something like white noise? A hiss? Do you mean it swells and fades?

Comment: First of all, Welcome to Sound Design! You said the sound lasts for 5 or 6 seconds, but starting when? What I mean is: Does it happen right when you turn it on, as soon as input is removed, or anything else? That may help narrow down the issued.

Comment: I’m guessing they’re probably active speakers then? Or are you using a class A amplifier randomly? Is it only one speaker in the array?

Comment: I have a similar issue with my studio monitors here at home. I strongly suspect one of the amplifier power supply capacitors is losing it's effectiveness. Would suggest attempting to do some elimination testing. Switch outputs to narrow down the source of the issue - possibly get a replacement amplifier if you are not using active speakers.

Comment: thank you for the fast response and the welcome. yes is something like a white noise but with an emphasis on lower frequencies. "it swells and fades" and this happens randomly 2 or 3 times after I switch the ACTIVE speakers on, and only in the right set of speakers.  Never when music or anything else is playing. They are four speakers in the array and they are permanently placed 10-12 feet off the floor.